# What does it mean that the spectrum is discrete?

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory

Let $T$ be some operator on a Hilbert space. What does it mean that the spectrum is discrete?

Comment: Discerte spectrum is the set of eigen values.

Comment: No, the set of eigen values is the spectrum, whether it is discrete or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Discrete" here means "not continuous".  If the spectrum of an operator is "all integers" then its spectrum is discrete.  If the spectrum of an operator is "all real numbers from 0 to 2, inclusive" then its spectrum is continuous, not discrete.

For example, the operator $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}$, on the interval [0, 1], has eigenvalue equation $\frac{d^2f}{dx^2}= \alpha f$ with boundary conditions f(0)= 0, f(1)= 0.

In order to have non trivial solution to that equation, the eigenvalues, $\alpha$ must be $(n\pi)^2$ for some integer n and the corresponding eigenvectors are $sin(n\pi x)$.
The spectrum is the set of all numbers of the form $(n\pi)^2$ for n a positive integer.  The spectrum, the set of all eigenvalues, is "discrete".